# UIView animation being held up on main thread

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have some nested UIView animations like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    //Animation
}completion:^(BOOL success){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        //More animation
    }completion:^(BOOL success){

    }];
}];
```

The inside animation occasionally has a delay before starting when there's other activity on the thread.

I was wondering if there was a way around this, and if GCD can be used here to run this on a background thread? It's UI code, so perhaps not.

Comment: What is the main thread busy doing?

Comment: UI code can only be run on the Main Thread. It will crash otherwise. You should look into why the Main Thread is so busy, and perhaps move some of those computations to other Threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not too obvious an answer, a way around your problem would be:

```
[UIView
    animateWithDuration:1.0
    animations:^{
         //Animation
    }];
[UIView
    animateWithDuration:1.0
    delay:1.0
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
    animations:^{
        //More animation
    }
    completion:^(BOOL success) {}];
```

i.e. just schedule the second animation at the same time as you schedule the first, but tell it not to start until you know the first will be finished.

Once things are scheduled, Core Animation isn't blocked by main queue activity so you can be busy a second later and the second thing will still start immediately after the first has finished.

Comment: This has it's problems and isn't perfect, but I think it's a decent workaround solution.